# How can I avoid the AWS stack drift false positive on s3 bucket ObjectOwnership?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-s3

When I deploy an s3 bucket with ObjectOwnership: `BucketOwnerPreferred` the stack drift reports a false positive:

Property: OwnershipControls
Change: REMOVE
Expected Value: {"Rules":[{"ObjectOwnership":"BucketOwnerPreferred"}]}
Actual Value: -

But S3 reports the ownership is indeed BucketOwnerPreferred.

Answer (score 0):

i'm having the same issue.
What's more interesting is that if I disable the ACL from the console (instead of CFN), it doesn't detect the drift.

Comment: According to SO rules what you wrote is not an answer but you should post similar sentences as a comment in future please

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).